# Wix: Passing a property back from a C# custom action

Tags: c#, windows, wix, installation, windows-installer

Is it possible to pass a property back from a WiX custom action? I've been trying to figure out a solution for hours now, I've seen many answers but none of them work for me. Here's what I tried,

**C# (Custom Action)**

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult TestAction(Session session)
    {
        session["FOO"] = "BAR";
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**WiX FooDlg.wxs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <Property Id="FOO"/>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="FooDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Foo">

        <Control Id="FOO" Type="Edit" Property="FOO" Height="17" Width="45" X="50" Y="150" Text="[FOO]" Indirect="no"/>

        <Control Id="FOO" Type="PushButton" X="150" Y="200" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Test FOO">
          <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="Testing">1</Publish>
        </Control>

      </Dialog>
    </UI>
    <CustomAction Id='FOO' BinaryKey='FooBinary' DllEntry='TestAction' Execute='immediate' Return='check'/>
    <Binary Id='FooBinary' SourceFile='FOO.dll'/>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can pass a property back from the custom action in the installer. Make sure the property is public (only upper case letters in its name) and that your custom action is scheduled as immediate and executes before your corespondent dialog loads (use a verbose log to track the property values during the execution of your installer, just search for the property name in it).

Comment: You may also need to mark it as Secure if you plan on using it in the InstallExecuteSequence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Id of your CustomAction in the Publish tag:

```
<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="FOO">1</Publish>
```